# Nested Cursor & Recursion in PL/SQL

Tags: recursion, plsql, nested, database-cursor

I'm new to PL/SQL and have just started working with cursors. I'm writing a small program to print the recursive trace for an employee -> supervisor all the way to the big boss. Essentially my query will output employee, supervisor1, then output supervisor1, supervisor2, all the way to supervisorn, null. My goal is to write a short PL/SQL program that will iterate this process for each employee. My code is as follows:

```
set serveroutput on;

DECLARE
    v_iteration number := 0;

BEGIN
    for x in (select * from e)
    loop
        dbms_output.put_line('recursive trace #' || v_iteration);
        v_iteration := v_iteration + 1;
        for y in 
            (WITH sup_hierarch (employee, supervisor) AS
            (select x.ssn, x.superssn FROM e
            UNION ALL
            select supervisor, superssn
            from sup_hierarch join e on sup_hierarch.supervisor = e.ssn
            where sup_hierarch.supervisor is not null)
            select * from sup_hierarch)


        loop
            dbms_output.put_line(y.employee || ', ' || y.supervisor);
        end loop;


    end loop;
END;
/
```

I've used two implicit cursors, the outer implicit cursor is used to loop through the employee table (in order to print the recursive trace for each employee), and the inner implicit cursor is used to loop through the recursive trace itself. The code somewhat works, sample output:

```
recursive trace #6
666884444, 333445555
666884444, 333445555
666884444, 333445555
666884444, 333445555
666884444, 333445555
666884444, 333445555
666884444, 333445555
666884444, 333445555
333445555, 888665555
333445555, 888665555
333445555, 888665555
333445555, 888665555
333445555, 888665555
333445555, 888665555
333445555, 888665555
333445555, 888665555
888665555,
888665555,
888665555,
888665555,
888665555,
888665555,
888665555,
888665555,
```

Based on the entirety of my output, the loop through each employee is working correctly. Furthermore, the recursive trace for each employee is working correctly (that is, each employee has correct recursive depth & stack). However, each line in the recursive trace is printing number_of_employee times, when I expected it to be printed once. Why is this?

Comment: How many rows does the WITH factoring clause return when you execute it? Could it be because of UNION ALL? What happens if you use UNION?

Comment: The WITH clause should return just the specified columns for the (single) row that the cursor is currently pointing to. The WITH clause statement will be executed each time the cursor iterates through the table, returning one row at a time. Hence, the recursive query will be ran for each employee. Maybe there's a bug in the join logic (the statement that is UNION ALL'd also joins on the WITH view). Using UNION instead of UNION ALL gives me an error stating that recursive WITH clauses must use UNION ALL.

Comment: This can be done with 1 SQL statement. See [Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm) and/or google "Oracle Hierarchical Queries"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is the first part of your WITH clause: it returns the same date for as many rows as there are in 'e'.
Why not just do it like this:

```
    DECLARE
        v_iteration number := 0; -- useless in the version

    BEGIN
        for y in 
                (WITH sup_hierarch (employee, supervisor) AS
                (select x.ssn, x.superssn FROM e
                UNION ALL
                select supervisor, superssn
                from sup_hierarch join e on sup_hierarch.supervisor = e.ssn
                where sup_hierarch.supervisor is not null)
                select * from sup_hierarch)
        loop
            dbms_output.put_line(y.employee || ', ' || y.supervisor);
        end loop;

    END;
    /
```

and if you want 2 loops, just to get your iterations:

```
    DECLARE
        v_iteration number := 0;

    BEGIN
        for x in (select * from e)
        loop
            dbms_output.put_line('recursive trace #' || v_iteration);
            v_iteration := v_iteration + 1;
            for y in 
                (WITH sup_hierarch (employee, supervisor) AS
                (select x.ssn, x.superssn FROM dual
                UNION ALL
                select supervisor, superssn
                from sup_hierarch join e on sup_hierarch.supervisor = e.ssn
                where sup_hierarch.supervisor is not null)
                select * from sup_hierarch)


            loop
                dbms_output.put_line(y.employee || ', ' || y.supervisor);
            end loop;


        end loop;
    END;
    /
```

Comment: Thank you! The first query gives the correct number of result rows, and the correct data per row, however the order is incorrect which, when printing a recursive trace, is important to have correct. On the other hand, the second program works _exactly_ as I had envisioned. Thank you. Whats the rationale behind using dual?

Comment: The recursive with clause needs 2 queries, and in you case, the first one is just to get the fixed starting params that are read from the outer loop. So you need a table that has just 1 row, and DUAL is your best friend in this case. As for the order, remember that SQL does NOT guarantee an ordering of the results  unless you have an ORDER BY.

Comment: Right, I understand that SELECT statements do not guarantee ordering unless there is an associated ORDER BY statement, however, in this specific case, we are using a cursor to iterate row by row and accessing these rows using dual. Furthermore, the next row is functionally dependent upon the previous row due to the requirement imposed by recursion (based on join statement). Therefore, the we should know exactly what line put_line to output.   Since we are stepping row by row in the second solution, it maintained the integrity of order. But in the first, I think we are stepping table by table.